# Does Raspbian come installed with PyOpengl?

Tags: python

Pretty much just what the title is, does it? I want to know since I want to learn opengl using python...

Comment: Probably not installed by default but the PyOpenGL site claims experimental support from GLES 1 to 3.1 which covers the Pi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `python-opengl` package isn't contained<sup>*</sup> in the Raspbian image by default, but you can easily install it:

```
sudo apt-get install python-opengl
```

<sub>* Here's the complete list of pre-installed packages in the current Raspbian image: http://pastebin.com/8W3i8bms</sub>

Comment: Thanks! You even saved me the trouble of looking for the command thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You may use `apt-cache` command to find out what packages are **available** for your system.

In your particular case:

```
$ apt-cache search opengl | grep python
python-glitch - Python library for OpenGL graphics programming
python-gtkglext1 - GtkGLext python bindings
python-opengl - Python bindings to OpenGL           <-- here it is!!
python-pyside.qtopengl - Qt 4 OpenGL module - Python bindings
python-qt3-gl - Qt3 OpenGL bindings for Python
[...]
```

Comment: Wait so does this mean that it is installed?

Comment: No, this says it's *available*, not necessarily installed.

Answer (score 1):

n.st's solution works fine for python2.  If you happen to have a python3 app you will want to

```
sudo apt-get install python3-opengl
```