# What packages are pre-installed on the current Raspbian image?

Tags: raspbian, packages

[This question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15843/does-raspbian-come-installed-with-pyopengl/) gave me the idea that it might be handy to have a list of all packages that are pre-installed on the [Raspberry Pi Foundation's Raspbian image](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/).

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be an official list, but it's easy to create one by downloading, extracting and mounting a Raspbian (or any other Debian) image and then following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/181544/).

```
grep -oP '(?<=Package: )\S+' /mnt/raspbian/var/lib/apt/extended_states | sort > /tmp/raspbian-packages.txt
```

… and out pops a list of 407 packages (for the current version, as of this post, 2014-01-07): http://pastebin.com/8W3i8bms

Comment: usually, most people are interested in "what packages were pre-installed on MY system", and on a working system your script gives wrong results, because it clearly does not distinguish between pre-installed and manually installed packages.

Comment: @lenik I understand that that might be of interest too, but it isn't the point of this question. You can take a look at the [question I linked to above](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages) for instructions on how to get a list of all manually installed packages on a running system.

Comment: yeah, I saw that. you copy-pasted an answer from another site, and asked a question to fit the answer. good job!

Comment: @lenik As I said, I needed this list to back up my answer to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15843/does-raspbian-come-installed-with-pyopengl/) and wanted to share it so others wouldn't have to go through the same steps in case they needed it. I'm sorry if it offends you that I had to look up how to get the list and even had the nerve to cite my sources. (Oh, and I forgot to point out that I didn't invent the positive look-behind regex either…)

Answer (score 0):

when used on real system, the correct list of the automatically installed packages could be found using `apt-mark showautomatic` and the list of the manually installed packages could be seen using `apt-mark showmanual`.

for those who don't like a simple solution, but prefers grepping some files, here's another (still correct) approach:

```
cat /var/lib/apt/extended_states | grep -B 1 "Auto-Installed: 1" | grep "Package" | sed "s/Package: //"|sort > apt_auto-installed_packages.txt

cat /var/lib/apt/extended_states | grep -B 1 "Auto-Installed: 0" | grep "Package" | sed "s/Package: //"|sort > apt_manually-installed_packages.txt
```

enjoy! =)